# How to draw into device context

Tags: winapi, gdi

I have a bitmap image in form of array of 32-bit integers (ARGB pixels: `uint32 *mypixels`) and `int width` and `int height`. I need to output them to a printer.

I have the printer context: `HDC hdcPrinter;`

As I learned, I need first to create a compatible context:

```
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcPrinter);
```

Then I need to create an `HBITMAP` object, select it into the compatible context, and render:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = ...?
SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
BitBlt(printerContext, 0, 0, width, height, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

And finally clean up:

```
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
DeleteDC(hdcMem);
```

My question is how do I create an `HBITMAP` object and put `mypixels` into it?

I found two options:

1. `HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcPrinter, width, height);`

   Looks good, but how do `mypixels` get into this bitmap?
2. `HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdcPrinter /*or hdcMem?*/, ...);`

   Will it work? Is it better than option 1.?

Comment: you can use or [SetDIBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162973(v=vs.85).aspx) after [CreateCompatibleBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183488(v=vs.85).aspx) - or better do this in single call [CreateDIBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183491(v=vs.85).aspx) - `creates a compatible bitmap (DDB) from a DIB and, optionally, sets the bitmap bits`

Comment: Lots of ways, matters where it comes from.  Basically from a file, a resource, a memory location.  You'll have to focus on the source of the bitmap, the code snippet automatically pops out from any basic Google query.  Note the bug in your code, you can never ignore the return value of SelectObject().  The device context has to be restored, failure to do so causes a memory leak.  Using a library to do this is strongly recommended, also helps to avoid googling.

Answer (score 2):

This function creates a bitmap and sets it to an initial image.
Irt's a bit fiddly to access the bits directly, but it can be done.

```
HBITMAP MakeBitmap(unsigned char *rgba, int width, int height, VOID **buff)
{
    VOID *pvBits;          // pointer to DIB section 
    HBITMAP answer;
    BITMAPINFO bmi;
    HDC hdc;
    int x, y;
    int red, green, blue, alpha;

    // setup bitmap info   
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;         // four 8-bit components 
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = width * height * 4;

    hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(0));
    answer = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pvBits, NULL, 0x0);
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            red = rgba[(y*width + x) * 4];
            green = rgba[(y*width + x) * 4 + 1];
            blue = rgba[(y*width + x) * 4 + 2];
            alpha = rgba[(y*width + x) * 4 + 3];
            red = (red * alpha) >> 8;
            green = (green * alpha) >> 8;
            blue = (blue * alpha) >> 8;
            ((UINT32 *)pvBits)[(height - y - 1) * width + x] = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
        }
    }
    DeleteDC(hdc);

    *buff = pvBits;

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Who is responsible for cleaning up `*buff`? Which allocator is needed to dispose `*buff`? It's probably also a good idea to use the `Get{R|G|B}Value` [color macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183456.aspx), as well as the [RGB macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162937.aspx). Evaluating the alpha channel and setting it is usually not necessary, since the GDI doesn't support alpha transparency.

Comment: @IInspectable - `GDI doesn't support alpha transparency` - yes ? strange why this work for me.

Comment: I believe *buff dies when you call DeleteObject on the hBitmap. You shouldn't try to free it or allocate it with your own allocators or malloc().

Comment: @RbMm: *"strange why this work for me."* - I don't know, what *"this"* is. If you are referring to copying bytes around memory, then this works because it neither involves GDI, nor does it implement alpha transparency.

Comment: @RbMm: `AlphaBlend` does not support true per-pixel alpha transparency (which is the only reason why you'd want to have a dedicated alpha channel). Anyway, `AlphaBlend` is the single notable exception. Everything else in GDI does not support alpha transparency.

Comment: @IInspectable - `does not support true per-pixel alpha transparency` - really it full support this

Comment: @RbMm: As I said, it's the **single** notable exception. Everything else in GDI doesn't support alpha transparency. And copying bytes around in memory certainly isn't alpha transparency, nor GDI rendering.

Comment: @IInspectable - here code for create bitmap special for use with `AlphaBlend` , operations like `green = (green * alpha) >> 8;` this is premultiplied alpha - then this used with [`AC_SRC_ALPHA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183393(v=vs.85).aspx) - `BLENDFUNCTION sbf = { AC_SRC_OVER, 0, 255, AC_SRC_ALPHA };`

Comment: @RbMm: Can we stop this now? `AlphaBlend` is the **single** notable exception. Everything else in GDI doesn't support alpha transparency. And copying bytes around memory is not alpha blending, as you seemed to imply.

Comment: this is code for create bitmap which than can be used with AlphaBlend

Comment: @RbMm: The OP is calling `BitBlt`.